# Insert multiple TXT files into word with filename

Tags: vba, ms-word, extract

I would like to insert multiple .txt files into one big docx document, with the filename before the content of each txt file.

Until now this works great :

```
Sub A_Import_text()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document, txtFile As Document
strFolder = GetFolder("")
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.txt", vbNormal)
Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
While strFile <> ""
  Set txtFile = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False)
  wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter txtFile.Range.Text & vbCr
  txtFile.Close SaveChanges:=True
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set txtFile = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

But I cannot retrieve the filename before the content of the txt files.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: `wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter strFile & vbCr & txtFile.Range.Text & vbCr`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the filename with a carriage return as part of the text that is getting inserted.

```
wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter strFile & vbCr & txtFile.Range.Text & vbCr
```